У меня дома (at my home)
For "at my home", why don't we say у моего дома? Is меня in genitive or accusative in this case?
Is дома an adverb or a genitive of дом here? Do they have to be put together as such?
Большое спасибо.

Well меня is definitely genitive, governed by у. I think this question relates to natural idiom in the language. Compare chez moi in French.


Is меня in genitive or accusative in this case?

Russian has a feature called "proximal possession". The most natural way of conveying the concept of "I have (something)" is saying у меня есть, literally, "at me there is".
The agent should be put into the genitive, that's the only case that the preposition у governs.
This construct can also be used (like in this case) to replace possessive pronouns and adjectives in objects. For instance, Russian for "The pencil is in my backpack" would be карандаш у меня в рюкзаке, literally, "(the) pencil (is) at me in (the) backpack".
So у меня дома, which literally means "at me at home", means "at my home, at my place", when used as an object. У меня дома тепло would mean "my place is warm" (literally, "at me at home (it's) warm"), and встретимся у меня дома would mean "we'll meet at my place"

Is дома an adverb or a genitive of дом here? Do they have to be put together as such?

It's an adverb, a very old one, originating from either an old locative or an old genitive form of домъ, neither of which is attested in isolation.

For "at my home", why don't we say у моего дома?

У моего дома is a valid, grammatical phrase, but it doesn't mean "at my home".
У моего дома is not a proximal possessive clause anymore. It literally means "next to my house", that is, outside your literal house but close to it.
У моего дома полицейская машина would mean "there's a police car next to my house", while у меня дома полицейская машина would mean "I have a police car at my home".
Same as in English, you can use "home" in the figurative sense, for instance в Москве я у себя дома, meaning "in Moscow, I'm at home". It wouldn't work using the word "house" (in either language).

Does у have a meaning of возле at the same time of "at"?

@Judicaël Lamyrtille Yes, it some case it does. It is synonymous to "возле" (at) or "рядом с" (next to) when people talk about places or locations. For example "Оставь у ворот" (Leave it near the gate) or "Встретимся у автобусной останоки" (Let's meet at the bus stop). In both examples you can interchange it with "возле" and it will be a correct sentence.

Both of phrases can be used, but they have a different meaning.
"У меня дома" refers to something being inside your home and can be applied to both inanimate objects and people (like both "There is a TV at my home" and "I have guests at my home" would use it "У меня дома есть телевизор", "У меня дома гости").
"У моего дома" on the other hand refers to something outside of your house again both animate and inanimate. Like "I have a shop next to my house" or "Meet me near my house" ("У моего дома есть магазин", "Встретимся у моего дома"). Here "y" means "nearby" ("рядом"). It also may refer to an attribute of the house itself like "My house have a green roof" ("У моего дома зелёная крыша").
All in all it seems that the difference comes from the different meanings of the word "дом": home vs house, but unfortunately I cannot give you a formal definition, why it is that way.
